# Timer in regionDidChange will not fire swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, timer, mapkit

I have a mapView where I want to enable continuous location tracking to be turned on or off. If it's on, I want it to temporarily pause when there is user interaction on the map, and to resume once user interaction has ended after a short timer. I'm trying to do this in `regionWillChange` and `regionDidChange`, with checks to see if the region was changed via user manipulation. The pausing works just fine, but when it comes time to resume the timer doesn't seem to ever come to completion.

```
func pauseTrack() {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    self.trackingMode = false
    self.shouldTrack = true
}

@objc func resumeTrack() {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.trackingMode = true
    self.shouldTrack = false
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let didMapTouchesBegin = mapTouchBegan()
    if (didMapTouchesBegin == true && self.trackingMode == true) {
        self.pauseTrack()

        if (self.resumeTimer != nil) {
            self.resumeTimer.invalidate()
        }

        self.countdownTime = 5.0
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let didMapTouchesEnd = mapTouchEnded()
    if (didMapTouchesEnd == true && self.shouldTrack == true) {
        print("tracking will resume")
        self.resumeTimer = Timer(timeInterval: self.countdownTime, target: self, selector: #selector(self.resumeTrack), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

func mapTouchBegan() -> Bool {
    let view = self.mapView.subviews[0]
    if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
            if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began) {
                print("user started touching screen")
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func mapTouchEnded() -> Bool {
    let view = self.mapView.subviews[0]
    if let gestureRecognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
        for recognizer in gestureRecognizers {
            if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended) {
                print("user finished touching screen")
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

The `print("tracking will resume")` outputs to the console as expected, and other console logging has confirmed that the tracking of inputs is working as intended, but for some reason the timer just doesn't work. I've confirmed that it isn't nil after creating it, and I've also tried creating it inside of `Dispatch.main.async { }` because I thought threading might be the problem, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You instantiated a timer, but never added it to any run loop with [`add(_:forMode:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop/1418468-add). In effect, you never started the timer.

Alternatively, and easier, you can both instantiate and start a timer using [`scheduledTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer).